# point site from godaddy to heroku via cloudflare

Tags: heroku, dns, cloudflare, nameservers, pointdns

I have a domain from godaddy which is pointed to heroku app with pointDNS. Now i want to manage my dns records on cloudflare which will change the way it is pointed, so ideally i want something like below

Godaddy(Domain registrar)--->Cloudflare(DNS manager)-->Heroku(hosting)

I have tried adding pointDNS NS to Cloudflare and Cloudflare ns to godaddy, but it didn't worked.

Comment: The DNS does not work like you seem to think. Once you decided that entity X is in charge of handling your nameservers (providing DNS service to you), you go to your registrar where you did buy this domain, you update the domain so that it now has the nameservers given to you by your provider. You wait "a little" and then everything works, and for any change of the content of the zone you go to entity X, which manages your nameserver and hence the content of the zone published.

Comment: Thanks Patrick I got your point as i am working with ns from last couple of years ,But what is the reason that we can't put ns provided by  one DNS service to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can skip pointDNS in this case.

Comment: so you mean so say there is no need of pointdns in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can use an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I figure it out

Step 1 - added custom domain in Heroku as per [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Step 2: Copy NS from  Cloudflare to GoDaddy

Step 3: Pointed via CNAME as Cloudflare allows naked domain pointing.

Comment: A bit late reply here but...Step 2 is the other way around.